# pymodbus USB connection issue

Tags: modbus, plc

I have a Click PLC that I am trying to read coil data from.  I am using pymodbus, but I am getting a connection error.  The only issue I can come up with is that I don't know if the port entry is correct.  I am using an RS-232 converter to USB.  The USB is on com4.  This there a reason I can't get a connection.  Simple code is below.

Thanks,
Marc

```
from pymodbus.client.sync import ModbusSerialClient

click = ModbusSerialClient(method='rtu',port='com4',baudrate=9600,parity='O')

outputLight = click.read_coils(8193,1,unit=1)

print outputLight
```

Comment: Please describe your connection: Is the Click PLC talking RS-485? How did you connect it to your RS-232 converter?

Answer (score 0):

You're missing something like:

```
click.connect()
```

After defining your connection and before reading coils.

As you say it seems some of your settings are not correct, maybe you can try something like QModMaster (I'm assuming you're on Windows). It will be easier to try different settings and ports faster, just to make sure you have the correct port at least. See here: https://sourceforge.net/projects/qmodmaster/